# Rake db:migrate returns "rake aborted! no such file to load -- spec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

For some reason, out of no where, rails began giving me an error on "rake db:migrate", and I can no longer run migrations. It returns the error "no such file to load -- spec /home/ti/rails_apps/appname/Rakefile:10"

I've spent two hours searching google for answers, trying to figure this out, but to no avail. What could be the problem?

Here is the trace:

```
-jailshell-3.2$ rake db:migrate --trace
(in /home/ti/rails_apps/teamisrael)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- spec
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/home/ti/rails_apps/teamisrael/vendor/plugins/google-geocoder/tasks/rspec.rake:5
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:7
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:7:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:7
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/ti/rails_apps/teamisrael/Rakefile:10
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2349:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2349:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1985:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1984:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1969:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1967:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/bin/rake:31
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its your google-geocoder plugin rake task that is requiring something you don't have?

```
/home/ti/rails_apps/teamisrael/vendor/plugins/google-geocoder/tasks/rspec.rake:5
```

Comment: I thought I might be missing rspec but I have installed it multiple times and it is still not working...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the stacktrace the `google-geocoder` plugin is requiring an older version of RSpec.